# RabbitMQ client throwing error while running docker-compose up command

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, jackrabbit

I am trying to run docker-compose with two .net core console applications having dependency of rabbitMQ, I am using Docker with Windows.

I have added to console application, as described on RabbitMQ official docs https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

Outside of both applications I have added docker-compose.yml

Folder structure:

### 1. Send

1. Send.cs (as it is in RabbitMQ docs)
2. Send.csproj
3. Dockerfile

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 as build-env
   WORKDIR /app

   # Copy the project file and restore the dependencies
   COPY *.csproj ./
   RUN dotnet restore

   # Copy the remaining source files and build the application
   COPY . ./
   RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

   # Build the runtime image
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Send.dll"]
   ```

### 2. Recieve

1. Recieve.cs (as it is in RabbitMQ docs)
2. Recieve.csproj
3. Dockerfile (Same as Sender Dockerfile except Send replaced with Recieve)

### 3. Docker-compose.yml

```
  version: '3'

    services:
      rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        ports:
          - "5672:5672"
          - "15672:15672"
        container_name: rabbitmq
        hostname: my-rabbit
      Send:
        image: sender
        build:
          context: ./Send
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq
      Reciever:
        image: reciever
        build:
          context: ./Recieve
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq
```

Error Thrown

> Unhandled Exception:
>   RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the
>   specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException: One
>   or more errors occurred. (Connection failed) --->
>   RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
>   ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException:
>   Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672

Comment: Are you connecting to the `rabbitmq` service from your host?

Comment: I am new to it, i have added RabbitMQClient from nuget package in both of applications. and i ma building(running up) compose file from my system.

Comment: You did not answer my question; please try to answer it directly. Is RabbitMQ being connected to just within your containers (one container to another), or do you want to connect from your host (outside of Docker)?

Comment: In my case RabbitMQ is within containers (one container to another), not outside the docker.

Comment: Great. You can remove the port publishing related to `rabbitmq`, in that case. Only open ports to the host if you need them.

Comment: Thanks, @halfer for your support, still I have not got success, I have to be more learn/prepared. I have added a repository if u want u can review it https://github.com/harpalsingh1993/DockerDemo

Comment: I would simplify this a bit - remove the `networks` and all references to it - all containers will appear on the default network anyway. Also remove the `hostname: my-rabbit` for the RabbitMQ service, and connect to `rabbitmq` instead - a magic DNS entry is made for the service name by default. Remove the ports, as I have suggested.

Comment: If you are still having problems, please update the post here - you cannot now be getting `127.0.0.1:5672` in an error, since you are not connecting to localhost.

Comment: I have made the change but still getting same error while using docker-compose up

Comment: OK, please ask a new question about that, and put the link here if you wish (the problem as expressed above is presumably no longer happening, since you are no longer connecting to RabbitMQ on `127.0.0.1`). Victor has correctly answered your first problem, and now you have a new one. `:=)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor's answer was also helpful but, problem was the rabbitmq starting later, while send and receiver started before.

While I restarted the same stopped sender and receiver container, it was working as expected(because the rabbitmq container was up).
So I have added the retry policies on container, found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854997/6310485).

The final version of my docker-compose file is looking like below, and is working fine.
    version: '3'
    services:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: my-rabbit
    networks:
      - my-network-name
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:15672"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 5

  Send:
    image: sender
    build:
      context: ./Send
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - rabbitmq
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - my-network-name
    links: 
        - rabbitmq

  Reciever:
    image: reciever
    build:
      context: ./Recieve
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - rabbitmq
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - my-network-name
    links: 
        - rabbitmq
networks:
  my-network-name:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 4):

For making Docker containers able to communicate with each other, you need to set them in the same network. On your `docker-compose.yml` add the following:

```
version: '3'
    services:
      rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        ports:
          - "5672:5672"
          - "15672:15672"
        container_name: rabbitmq
        hostname: my-rabbit
        networks:
          - my-network-name
      Send:
        image: sender
        build:
          context: ./Send
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq
        networks:
          - my-network-name
      Reciever:
        image: reciever
        build:
          context: ./Recieve
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq
        networks:
          - my-network-name
networks:
  my-network-name:
    driver: bridge
```

As you can see, all the containers are in the same network, and they can communicate in the next way:

```
http://<container_name>:<port>
```

So if you want the **Sender** sends a message to **RabbitMQ** then:

```
amqp://rabbitmq:5672
```

If you use `localhost` as an IP inside any container, it will use its loopback interface, receiving the request itself.

Comment: Thanks, @Victor for your support, still I have not got success, I have to be more learn/prepared. I have added a repository if u want u can review it https://github.com/harpalsingh1993/DockerDemo

Comment: As per my comments on the other thread, I recommend you ask a new question Harpal, since Victor's solution for your first problem appears to be correct.